# How to disable release notes when open package management console

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package

When in Visual Studio 2017 you open

> Package management console

it automatically open **Release notes** tab, how to make it stop doing it? 
[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want to stop display the release `Each package is licensed to you by its owner. ... Package Manager Console Host Version 4.4.0.4475. Type 'get-help NuGet' to see all available NuGet commands.` when you open Package management console? Could I know the reason you want to do that? Since this will give some useful info and you can use the Clear Console button to clear those info.

Comment: Again, if understand you correct, you are challenging VS\NuGet design, you should discuss this question on the GitHub:https://github.com/NuGet

Comment: Please check updated screen

Comment: Thanks for your update. According to the screen, the release notes seems about post-mark, have you ever install any nuget package about post-mark for your projects? You can confirm this issue with new create solution.